# Load component from interceptor

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am planning to handle network error at central point. So I am using interceptors for the same. Now I have a challenge, suppose I have got session time out in response (of any request) and I want to redirect user to the login page.
    In Ionic NavController is the solution to load any component (page).
    How can I use this NavController to load page/component in Interceptor.

```
Here is my interceptor:

export class PostInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {    
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
{
    let postReq = req.clone();
    let authenticationToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    postReq.headers.set('Content-Type','application/json');

    if(authenticationToken != null) {
       postReq.headers.append('Bearer',authenticationToken);
    }
    return next.handle(postReq).do(event => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        /*const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
        console.log(`Request happened at ${time}.`);*/
        if(event.body.loggedIn != null) {
          //loggedIn = false
          if(!event.body.loggedIn) {

          }
          else {
            //Do Nothing
            console.log('LoggedIn True')
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log(event.body);
          AppModule.map.set('prevRequest',postReq);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an Observable and Subject to do so.

For example http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Applied to your case:

First you create a service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private requestInterceptedSource: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
    requestIntercepted: Observable<number> = this.requestInterceptedSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {
    }

    getInterceptedSource(): Subject<number> {
        return this.requestInterceptedSource;
    }

}
```

Then you use this service in your interceptor in order to propagate the error:

```
 export class PostInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 

       constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

       intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
       {
         // I didn't copy/pasted your code...of course you should still use it ;)

         // Here we start to propagate the error
    this.myService.getInterceptedSource().next(err.status);
       }
 }
```

Finally in your `app.component.ts` you watch (subscribe) to the subject in order to redirect (I would say setRoot since there was an error) to the page you want in case of error:

```
 private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private app: App, private myService: MyService) {

    this.subscription = this.myService.requestIntercepted.subscribe((errorCode: number) => {this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('YourPage'});

}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the built in Events to handle my redirects and timeouts.  I have an HTTP interceptor for outgoing calls and a response interceptor shown in the second snippet below.  Only showing the response interceptor for this post.  Here is the shameless blog post I created:

[Ionic: Handle 401 & 408 HTTP Responses in Interceptor](http://www.kevinmistry.com/blog/category/development/ionic-handle-http-response-error-codes-in-interceptor.html)

First in the app.component you will need to subscribe to the events you want to create.  As you can tell below, on an unauthorized I remove authentication and then set the root to my login page.  I also show a popup.  On a timeout I just display a popup.

```js
this.events.subscribe("unauthorized:requestError",
  () => {
    this.authenticationService.removeAuthentication()
      .then(() => {
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);

        const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: "Unauthorized",
          subTitle: "Your credentials have expired.  Please log back in.",
          buttons: ["OK"]
        });
        alert.present();
      });
  });

this.events.subscribe("timeout:requestError",
  () => {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Request Timeout",
      subTitle: "Please refresh or try your request again.",
      buttons: ["OK"]
    });
    alert.present();
  });
```

Next in the interceptor I use the Events in Ionic Angular to publish them when needed.  You will need to import them and then inject them into the constructor.

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Events } from "ionic-angular";
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    public events: Events
  ){}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.events.publish("unauthorized:requestError");
        } else if (err.status === 408) {
          this.events.publish("timeout:requestError");
        }
      } else if (err.name === "TimeoutError") {
        this.events.publish("timeout:requestError");
      }
    });

  }
}
```

I will say from above I have an extra timeout in mine which is when I reject calls after 15 seconds in my outgoing interceptor.  That is err.name === "TimeoutError".  They still call the same Event though.